# What does "bone on bone" mean?

Tags: meaning

Here it is:

> Power cleans are not like squats or deadlifts, movements that can be ground out to a **bone-on-bone** finish through perseverance and hard work.

Comment: Have you looked up the phrase in a dictionary or online? If so, what did you find, and why do you think what you have found does not address the meaning here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bone-on-bone usually refers to a painful intense pain experienced when the cartilage in your knee joint has worn away and the joint space has narrowed enough to leave the bones exposed and touching each other on movement. So when it refers to bone on bone perseverance it can be interpreted as Power Cleans being a difficult exercise that can only be completed with intensely painful perseverance .